# SQL select 1 to many within the same row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table with 1 record, which then ties back to a secondary table which can contain either no match, 1 match, or 2 matches.

I need to fetch the corresponding records and display them within the same row which would be easy using `left join` if I just had 1 or no matches to tie back, however, because I can get 2 matches, it produces 2 records.

**Example with 1 match:**

```
Select T1.ID, T1.Person1, T2.Owner
From T1
Left Join T2
  ON T1.ID = T2.MatchID
```

**Output**

```
ID   Person1  Owner1 
----------------------
1    John     Frank
```

**Example with 2 match:**

```
Select T1.ID, T1.Person1, T2.Owner
From T1
Left Join T2
  ON T1.ID = T2.MatchID
```

**Output**

```
ID   Person1  Owner 
----------------------
1    John     Frank
1    John     Peter
```

Is there a way I can formulate my select so that my output would reflect the following When I have 2 matches:

```
ID   Person1  Owner1   Owner2
-------------------------------
1    John     Frank     Peter
```

I explored Oracle `Pivots` a bit, however couldn't find a way to make this work.   Also explored the possibility of using `left join` on the same table twice using `MIN()` and `MAX()` when fetching the matches, however I can only see myself resorting this as a "no other option" scenario.

Any suggestions?

** EDIT **

@ughai - Using CTE does address the issue to some extent, however when attempting to retrieve all of the records, the details derived from this common table isn't showing any records on the LEFT JOIN unless I specify the "MatchID" (CASE_MBR_KEY) value, meaning by removing the "where" clause, my outer joins produce no records, even though the CASE_MBR_KEY values are there in the CTE data.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT TEMP.BEAS_KEY, 
       TEMP.CASE_MBR_KEY,
       TEMP.FULLNAME,
       TEMP.BIRTHDT,
       TEMP.LINE1,
       TEMP.LINE2,
       TEMP.LINE3,
       TEMP.CITY,
       TEMP.STATE,
       TEMP.POSTCD,
       ROW_NUMBER() 
  OVER(ORDER BY TEMP.BEAS_KEY) R
  FROM TMP_BEN_ASSIGNEES TEMP
  --WHERE TEMP.CASE_MBR_KEY = 4117398
)
```

The reason for this is because the ROW_NUMBER value, given the amount of records won't necessarily be 1 or 2, so I attempted the following, but getting **ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery**

```
--// BEN ASSIGNEE 1
LEFT JOIN CTE BASS1
  ON BASS1.CASE_MBR_KEY = C.CASE_MBR_KEY  
 AND BASS1.R IN (SELECT min(R) FROM CTE A WHERE A.CASE_MBR_KEY = C.CASE_MBR_KEY)
--// END BA1 

--// BEN ASSIGNEE 2
LEFT JOIN CTE BASS2
  ON BASS2.CASE_MBR_KEY = C.CASE_MBR_KEY  
 AND BASS2.R IN (SELECT MAX(R) FROM CTE B WHERE B.CASE_MBR_KEY = C.CASE_MBR_KEY)
--// END BA2
```

** EDIT 2 **

Fixed the above issue by moving the Row number clause to the "Where" portion of the query instead of within the JOIN clause.  Seems to work now.

Comment: this is clearly a pivot thing. invest time in getting pivot running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER()` with 2 `LEFT JOIN` OR with `PIVOT` like this.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d5048/8)

**Query with Multiple Left Joins**

```
WITH CTE as 
(
  SELECT MatchID,Owner,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Owner) r FROM t2
)
select T1.ID, T1.Person, t2.Owner as Owner1, t3.Owner as Owner2 
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN CTE T2
ON  T1.ID = T2.MatchID AND T2.r = 1
LEFT JOIN CTE T3
ON T1.id = T3.MatchID AND T3.r = 2;
```

**Query with PIVOT**

```
WITH CTE as 
(
  SELECT MatchID,Owner,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Owner) R FROM t2
)
SELECT ID, Person,O1,O2
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN CTE T2
ON  T1.ID = T2.MatchID
PIVOT(MAX(Owner) FOR R IN (1 as O1,2 as O2));
```

**Output**

```
ID  PERSON  OWNER1  OWNER2
1   John    Maxwell Peter
```

Comment: seems to be mssql... oracle was asked

Comment: [CTE](https://community.oracle.com/thread/921467) is available in oracle as well. check the fiddle :)

Comment: @swe: Oracle had common table expressions (`with...`) long before SQL Server.

Comment: @swe - OP is very explicit about it in the description *"ties back to a secondary table which can contain either no match, 1 match, or 2 matches"*

Comment: @ughai - Got it!  Used the CTE, and because the row_number() values required a bit more logic given the CTE data contained additional data associated to other matches, I simply had to add the addition min() and max() row number logic to the "where" clause instead of the "join" and seems to work!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you know there are at most two matches, you can also use aggregation:

```
Select T1.ID, T1.Person1,
       MIN(T2.Owner) as Owner1,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(t2.Owner) <> MAX(t2.Owner) THEN MAX(t2.Owner) END) as Owner2
From T1 Left Join
     T2
     on T1.ID = T2.MatchID
Group By t1.ID, t1.Person1;
```